# How to manage images with image database field?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

In the LightSwitch 2012 HTTP Client solution, How to manage images within forms?. I want to upload/Edit images fields from sql database but this fields only shows blank space and nothing Action when I tap over them.

Only I want to do is when I tap over the image field opens popup and select a image I want to save to the "photo" field on sql database table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue I use custom control in image field (within the screen design) and then I put this code in control:

myapp.AddEditMonumentoItem.ImagenPrincipal_render = function (element, contentItem) {

createImageUploader(element, contentItem, "max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px");

};

Previusly I add jquery-uploader.js and image-uploader-base64-encoder.aspx files to project script folder .